# ¿Como saber cuentas lineas tenga un archivo csv?

Tags: python

Quiero saber cuentos lineas tengo en un archivo csv con un delimitador tabulación. Intento lo siguiente en un archivo `countRowsCSV.py`:

```
import csv

with open('archivo.csv',"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = "\t")
    data = list(reader)
    row_count = len(data)

    print row_count
```

Pero me conteste el terminal :

```
$ python countRowsCSV.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "countRowsCSV.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = list(reader)
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Comment: He probado tu codigo en python2 y python3, y funciona, podrias compartir el archivo .csv en archivo zip para poder testearlo y revisar cual es el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error en principio está generado por intentar leer un archivo que usa un fin de linea distinto al usado por tu SO (LF (`\n`) en Linux) como CR+LF(`\r\n`) o CR(`\r`) o alguna incosistencia en los finales de línea. Es común que ocurran esto con ficheros creados con  Excel que contienen por ejemplo celdas vacías.

Intenta abrir el documento en modo [universal-newline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) como la propia excepción te sugiere, para ello:

```
with open('archivo.csv',"rU") as f:
```

Si quieres solo obtener el número de lineas y no necesitas el contenido te sugiero usar `sum` con un generador:

```
with open('archivo.csv',"rU") as f:
    row_count = sum(1 for row in f)
```

Answer (score -2):

Lo pude conseguir con `open()` indicando el nombre y ruta del fichero ("your_file.csv"), en modo de sólo lectura (`"r"`), e ignorando los errores (`errors='ignore'`):

```
with open('your_file.csv', "r", errors='ignore') as f:
     row_count = sum(1 for row in f)

print(row_count)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda revisar [answer], edita tu respuesta, as respuestas deben realizarse en idioma español, saludos